# How can i force a number field to accept only 100s or 1000s or increaments of 100

Tags: php

I need to restrict a field to accept only value in increments of 100s. This field must accept only round figures. So it can only be 100, 200, 300 or 20,100, 20,200, 20,300 etc.

Note: this restriction is to be applied on a number field

I'm using PHP and Javascript and am fairly new at both.

Thank you

Comment: and what have you **tried yourself** so far?

Comment: % 100 == 0. A simple google will tell you this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use java script function to check the entered value is a multiple of 100. if no clear the field.
Please see the below

```js
function checkNum(num)
{
 var value = parseInt(num.value);
    console.log(value);
 if(!((value % 100) == 0) || value=='NaN')
   num.value=''; 
 
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number" onBlur="checkNum(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add pattern to the input field

`<input type="text" pattern="^[1-9]+[0-9]*00$" />`